# What does the 4th column in ls -l mean

Tags: command-line, ls

```
column 1 defines type of file and file permissions.** 
column 2 defines - i d k 
column 3 identifies owner of the file
column 4 identifies - a user but not sure of the association
column 5 file size
column 6 month of creation 
column 7 day of creation
column 8 time of creation
column 9 filename
```

can someone fill in the details I missed out for column 2 and column 4? and kindly validate my understanding.
I have issued with file owner so hopefully some clarification can help solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth column is the group to which the file/directory/asset belongs.  Run the command `groups` to see what groups you belong to.

Comment: Thanks. It was of the root group I think that's why I had no permissions on the file despite being the owner. I changed ownership using chown...

Answer (score 4):

In the output:

```
2nd column will tell you about the number of links to the file, 
4th columns is associated group of the file.
```

Comment: thanks @ravan. can file belong to more than one group ?